# Can I catch LogCat messages when using the phone normally (not connected to the pc)?

Tags: android, logcat

I want to know if there's any way of recording logcat's messages when I'm testing my app with a real phone in a real environment. What I'm trying to achieve is to take my phone elsewhere and if anything goes wrong with my app, trace back why it went wrong. Especially if I give my app to a friend (or a boss) to try it out, they can't give me a lot of feedback on problems.

I could just print all the output to a .txt and then read it, but I'd like something a bit nicer

Any Ideas?

Comment: belongs to [android.stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 11):

Yep ! Install aLogcat ! Very useful :)

[aLogcat app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd)

Comment: Yes ! Once you have installed the app, press the menu Button and add a filter. Write the same filter you have in your Eclipse's logcat per example :)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create your own Log.java function and then just change the import function to match your Class. In your Log.java you could write all the logs to some buffer and periodically save it to sdcard.

one more way is to

open adb shell

```
logcat > \sdcard\log.txt &
```

This will continue to run until restart of phone.

Comment: shouldn't the phone be rooted to get the adb? the idea is to give my app to someone and when they come to me with a problem I can take a look at what happened, in that case your first answer works very well

Comment: you dont need root access to run logcat from adb shell